# Real-time audio on multi-core Linux system

Tags: linux, audio, kernel, real-time

I'm working on an audio application on a multi-core (Debian) Linux machine with an RT kernel. The audio source generation takes a lot of processing time which can't be handled by a single core, so I have three different threads:

1. The main portaudio thread running on core 0
2. Source generation 1 running on core 1
3. Source generation 2 running on core 2

Thread 2 and 3 are writing to a ringbuffer, while thread 1 is reading data from the ringbuffer and sums it into the portaudio buffer.

I've tried many buffer sizes and scheduling policies, my best result was FIFO policy with audio buffer size of 16 stereo samples and ringbuffer size of 576. This solution generates more than 13ms (576/44100*1000) latency, which is too much.

I'm sure that this latency can be reduced, but I'm not an expert in Linux scheduling. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you keep RT prio of your process above any other on the core the policy doesn't matter.

Make sure you kick any other application out of the cores you use for RT (e.g. with `isolcpus=` kernel cmdline parameter).  Otherwise the low-prio processes can trigger I/O which will block your RT threads. You should also assign all the interrupts your application doesn't care about to the unused core. Actually I would suggest using core0 for normal tasks and cores 1,2,3 for RT in your case, because since core0 is the boot CPU it will have to perform some special housekeeping tasks.

Once you partition the system as described above try latency-measurement tools to figure out what is causing delays. Googling `linux rt latency trace` will give you a lot of useful links. This is the basic one: http://people.redhat.com/williams/latency-howto/rt-latency-howto.txt

If it turns out some kernel processing is blocking your app you may find a solution by looking at the description of kernel threads here: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/kernel-per-CPU-kthreads.txt

You should definitely be able to go below 2ms.